# Odoo. How to save data in database from ajax in controller

Tags: python-2.7, orm, odoo

I have odoo 10

my model

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'some.model'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name')
    description = fields.Text()
    published = fields.Date()
```

my controller

```
class MyController(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/api/save', auth='public', methods=['POST'],
                website=True, csrf=False)
    def save_obj(self, **kw):
        obj = json.loads(kw.get('data'))
        http.request.env['some.model'].write({
            'name': obj.get('title'),
            'description': obj.get('description'),
            'published': obj.get('dates')[0].get('date'),
        })
```

I want to save data from Ajax in database. The method I wrote does not save data. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm, i fixed it

```
new_obj = http.request.env['some.model'].create({
            'name': obj.get('title'),
            'description': obj.get('description'),
            'published': obj.get('dates')[0].get('date'),
        })
```

Is it correct, help please?
And are there any best practice of interacting from controller to database?